# retrieve data from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql db with the information of a player. [image]

In there, there is something called "rank" and rank 5 equals to admin. So have can i retrieve the rank information so i can use it in:

```
if(rank == 5) {
// do stuff
} else {
// error message
}
```

I have tried to search for this, but i dont seem to find anything. So any help would be nice. Sry for my bad english

Comment: select rank from table.. Ask google how to use "select mysql"

Comment: This came up after quick google search: https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/website-design/using-php-and-mysql/grab-all-comments-from-database

It's even on the top 5!

Comment: If you do not have knowledge 'bout how to work with PHP, try some courses at for example Udemy, Codeschool, Sololearn. They will help you with the basics...

I encourage you to do so, I did too and it worked out... It will make some of our code that we've sent more clear.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$DB_Server = 'localhost';
$DB_User = 'root';
$DB_pass = '';
$database = 'SAMPLE';

$conn = mysqli_connect($DB_Server, $DB_User, $DB_pass, $database);


$rank = "";

$result = $conn->query("SELECT * from TableName where rank = '5'");

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    $rank = $row['rank'];
}

if($rank == 5)
{
    #do something
}else{
    #do something
}
?>
```

Comment: He does not have a MySQLi connection initialised in his question, so add it to yours :-)

Comment: Im just getting a white screen when i use this code

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  select * from table name  where rank =5
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this for your actual SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE rank = 5;
```

This will return all users that have that rank. If you wanted just one user add the where statement for the user name or ID, whatever unique field you have to use.

SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE rank = 5 AND username = USER_NAME;

For connecting to the database (if you need to know how to do that) google who to select with PHP.

Once you have the result as an array you would access the correct field of the returned row:

```
if($row['rank'] == 5) {
```

Any good tutorial on PHP and Mysql will explain that in more depth.

Answer (score 0):

New to the language?

```
try {
    // Try to connect to the database server
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // If throws an error, show the error message
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

// Query the table players and select all keys where rank equals to 5
$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM players where `rank` = 5");
// For each result (row) in the query as $row (iterating over the multiple rows)
foreach ($result as $row) {
    if($row['rank'] == 5) {
       echo '<span>'.$row['username'].'<\/span>';
       echo '<span>'.$row['rank'].'<\/span>';
       echo '<span>'.$row['email'].'<\/span>';
   }
}
```

Comment: Your checking $rank == 5 before the query is even done.

Comment: Ah I forgot... Has to be in the foreach :P
Edited

Comment: getting "unexpexted syntax, expecting "," or ")" at $result

Comment: Forgot to put the query between quotes

Comment: What problem are you experiencing? Maybe a stackoverflow chat?

Comment: Im getting the same of the html content twice under each other. I tried to use the code that @Angelica made, but that just gave me a white screen.

Comment: Screenshot please.

Comment: But i dont want to echo the data. I want to use it in an IF statement. see example on my thread.

Comment: You can do anything you want... This is just an example, I worked the if also.

Comment: If you have multiple rows in your table, you will have to iterate over them. You could do that by having an id (index) in your table or you could use a foreach loop. That was what I was doing.

Comment: So it would be something like this:

`foreach($result as $row) {
if($row['rank'] == 5) {
// Do your thing
}
} `

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP PDO class which is more fast and SQL Injection protected
Try

```
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=YourServerName;dbname=YourDatabaseName','YourUserName','YourDatabaseUser');   

$RankNum = 5;
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM YourTableName Where Rank=:RankNum");
$query->bindParam("RankNum", $RankNum);

$query->execute();

if($rows = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    //Write your logics here
    //right now just echoing all data returned by query
    echo json_encode($rows);
    $db = null;
}
else
{
    echo "No Record Found"; 
}
```

don't forget to change the placeholders YourServerName etc